# I cannot install local webpack-cli

Tags: webpack

I cannot install local webpack-cli

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webpack-cli@3.3.1 postinstall: `node ./bin/opencollective.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webpack-cli@3.3.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\gromit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-05-04T03_00_48_053Z-debug.log

Comment: Hi, can I suggest that you add a little more information on what IDE you are using if any and also to clean up the error response so that it is more clear what issue you are facing. Also providing a little more background on the program and what you have currently tried to research may help to clarify the issue for other users that would like to help answer your question.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem here while running Linux Mint 19 in VirtualBox... doing this via the bash terminal, not with an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Simply updating your version of node.js / npm should do the trick:
https://nodejs.org/en/download/